# Does Java also guarantee that all variable changes before synchronized will be visible to the next thread which synchronizes on same object?

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized, java-threads, happens-before

In the below code will Java ensure that latest copy of `a` is visible to the thread which calls `getAB()`?

I understand that the values returned by `getAB()` might not be the same as set by `setAB`, but will Java ensure that the value of `a` seen by other thread will always either be more recent or consistent with the value of `b`?

```
public class Pair {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Pair() {
        super();
    }

    public void setAB(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        synchronized (this) {
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public int[] getAB() {
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        arr[0] = a;
        synchronized (this) {
            arr[1] = b;
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

**Followup question**:  what happens if we move the `arr[0] = a;` statement to *after* the `synchronized` block?

Like this ...

```
public int[] getAB() {
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    synchronized (this) {
        arr[1] = b;
    }
    arr[0] = a;
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does java also guarantee that all variable changes before synchronized will be visible to the next thread which synchronizes on same object?

Yes it does ... assuming the mutex **has been** acquired by the next thread.

However.  In your example `getAB` is using `a` **before** it has synchronized on `this`, so `arr[0] = a` could assign a stale value.

Assuming that `setAB` is called before `getAB`, the *happens before* relationships in your example will be:

```
      this.a = a;  
  HB  this.b = b;  
  HB  released mutex in first thread
  HB  acquired mutex in second thread
  HB  arr[1] = b;
```

and separately

```
      arr[0] = a;
  HB  arr[1] = b;
```

From this we can deduce that

```
  this.b = b;  HB  arr[1] = b;
```

but we **cannot** deduce that

```
  this.a = a;  HB  arr[0] = a;   // FALSE!
```

---

Then you move `arr[0] = a;` to after the `synchronized` block, the updated value of `a` is now guaranteed to be visible.

I won't reproduce the full "happens before analysis", but now we get

```
  arr[1] = b;  HB  arr[0] = a;
```

and we can deduce that

```
  this.a = a;  HB  arr[0] = a;   // NOW TRUE!
```

---

Having said this, it is generally NOT recommended that you write code that relies on careful analysis of happens before relationships etcetera.  It is better to use the higher level synchronization classes, or (as in this case) just do all of the reading and writing of shared variables inside the `synchronized` block.

(Generally speaking, the performance benefit you get from clever implementations of concurrency is usually tiny compared to overall application performance.  And the long term cost of finding and fixing Heisenbugs caused by subtle synchronization code flaws can be huge.)

Comment: Thanks, What happens if instead of synchronization for b read/write we declare it volatile? does that changes anything ?

Comment: It has the same effect.  We exchange the HB between the lock release and acquire for a HB between a volatile write and a subsequent volatile read.

Comment: But what happens if another thread happens after the synchronized block and before the use of a and maybe changes the value of a?

Comment: They may / may not see the latest update. But the value they'll see will always be more recent or consistent with value of B. which is fine by my use case.

Comment: That's a different issue.  If you want to ensure that thread two sees thread one's values for 'a' and 'b' (or thread three's values), then **all** of the reads and **all** of the writes must be done in synchronized blocks.

Comment: Like I said, low level / "smart" concurrency is tricky and error prone.  Just do it the simple way.  (And don't confuse memory visibility with overall thread-safety ...)